# toggle function shuts everything down

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I bought an admin template based on bootstrap 3. Some of the containers have a toggle function; the problem is that if I click on it, it will open the container, but when I want to close it, it closes up the whole `<div class="row">`.

The html code of the toggle is:

```
<span class="tools pull-right"><a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chvron-up"></a></span>
```

I have not received any response from the developer and I don't know how to fix it. I uploaded the index file with all the js etc. I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you bought it an this is a problem you should contact the author, also what is in your JS ? Id rather not run through your whole scripts.

Comment: is there a other way to make this toggle ?

for example with a custom script or something like that ?

Comment: well your listening to the event on a CLASS which is wrong for starter as when you click it ALL of those class elements will be changed, this should be ID's as ID's are (supposed to be) unique..

Comment: may be there will be class like "expand" and  "collapse" .. so just see those class are properly get applied at proper time ...